# SSIS - check if row exists before importing from source to destination

Tags: ssis

Can someone please advise:

I have got SOURCE (which is OLD SQL Server) and we need to move data to new DESTINATION (which is NEW SERVER). So moving data between different instances.

I'm struggling how to write the package which looks up in destination first and check if row exists then do nothing else INSERT.

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Take an OLEBD Source, connect it with a Lookup task.
2. Select the column that can be looked up. There should be some kind of ID for you to do this. Also select all the columns that need to be passed(SSIS has provisions of applying check boxes).
3. Connect the lookup no match rows to an OLEDB destination, do the mapping, and you are done.

If you want to redirect all those matching rows to somewhere, say a notepad file, you can do that too...

Answer (score 0):

I would use an Lockup transformation and redirect match output to something else like a OLEDB command in there you can write a IF exist statement or create that in a stored procedure that way it will either insert data or update data not insert duplicates